# accessing APK contents from the code on android device

Tags: android, apk

I need to access contents of my application APK from the code of this same application running on device.
I wrote this code that works perferctly well and return the datа on my 2.2 and 2.3.3 devices.

**But Is it a legal way and will it work on all versions starting from 2.1 to any future or existing version?**

The main reason is to detect apk original signature or repacked apk.

Here is my code of accessing META-INF/CERT.RSA:

```
    String path = this.getApplication().getPackageCodePath();
    try
    {
        ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(path);
        ZipEntry zentry = zfile.getEntry("META-INF/CERT.RSA");
        long siz = zentry.getSize();

        byte[] buf=new byte[(int) siz];
        InputStream istream = zfile.getInputStream(zentry);

        int ret = istream.read(buf);
        istream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work.

At present it works up to latest Android 3.2, and no method from this approach is marked as deprecated.