# A third party file in Android apk root directory

Tags: android, apk

I found a strange apk, a third party (non-standard) file named 'encode' is in root directory of the apk, I am confused that how did the author pack this file into apk? and how to use it in code?

```
F:\abc>ls
AndroidManifest.xml  classes.dex          res
META-INF             encode               resources.arsc
assets               lib

F:\abc>
```

I'm sure this file is useful for the apk, it is not a invalid file.
Please help me, Thanks. :)

Comment: If the author wanted you to know how his/her application worked, then it would be open source somewhere. As you are asking this question I can only assume that it isn't and you want to infringe someone's intellectual property rights.

Comment: Sorry, I am only interested in the principle, because if a android app is developed by eclipse, third party files should not be generated in apk root directory.Even though you put a file to the source code root directory.

Comment: @NickT I don't know about where you are, but at least where I am the right to reverse engineer software in order to understand how it works is not something that intellectual property rights take away from us, and nor do I believe they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APK files are just zip files; you can put anything you like in one using a standard zip file management program.  For how to access it, see: [accessing APK contents from the code on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658595/accessing-apk-contents-from-the-code-on-android-device)

Comment: Yes, the way in that url works. Thanks :)